# Is it possible to embed Adobe flash into a react-native app?

Tags: flash, react-native

I'm considering to use react-native for an upcoming rewrite of an app that is currently implemented in Adobe AIR/flash.

I think react-native would be a good technology to build upon ... but the new app *must* be able to display flash content. We have literally hundreds and hundreds of flash files in production, so converting them to a different format or something similar is a no-go.

Of course, we don't expect flash support in iOS. But support under MS Windows is a must have.

Has anyone of you done this?

Maybe there are some resources I failed to find with $searchengine?

Comment: Where did you land in the end with this?